# Microstrategy: Loading Dynamic Images

Tags: image, dynamic, dashboard, business-intelligence, microstrategy

I was using Microstrategy web and looking for a solution to change the images dynamically as per the data selected/filtered. E.g. I created a document and have tried to link photos available on a shared path. Now what I want to do is if the user id is filtered from the data, I want to show the image of user along with the relevant user data. Kindly advise if it can be achieved in Microstrategy.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I fixed it by adding the custom unique URLs which can be done hosting a normal http server i.e. using python python -m http. server port. Some other available http servers like WAMP/LAMP can also be used for this purpose.